# How to append/concatenate strings in mule Transform message?

Tags: mule

I am trying to concatenate strings in mule Transform message like below, but I am getting the below exception at run time. Could anyone please kindly help me on this? I am new to mule as well.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    references : "" when payload[0].person_id==null otherwise "person/"+payload[0].person_id,
}
```

Exception ::

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing: 
    references : "" when payload[0].person_id==null otherwise "person/"+payload[0].person_id,
                                                              ^
Type mismatch for '+' operator
     found :string, :number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [Mule Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#using-concat-on-a-string) for Mule Dataweave operators. For concatenating string `++` operator should be used. Like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    references : "" when payload[0].person_id==null otherwise "person/" ++ payload[0].person_id
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

use ++ operator which is the concatenating operator in Dataweave.

Giving below the example from Mulesoft documentation

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  name: "Mule" ++ "Soft"
}
```

for more please read below documentation

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#concat

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  name: payload.firstName ++ payload.lastName
}
```

Make sure that any of the values (firstname or lastName) is not null.

Comment: How would you do this if the values could be null?